# How to access the resources like string defined in string.json under element folder from the java code?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I have defined a string name and value in the string.json under the element folder. How to access those values in the java code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Snippet to access String from strings.json

```java
 public static String getString(Context context, int id) {
        String result = "";
        if (context == null) {
            LogUtil.error(TAG, "getString -> get null context");
            return result;
        }
        ResourceManager manager = context.getResourceManager();
        if (manager == null) {
            LogUtil.error(TAG, "getString -> get null ResourceManager");
            return result;
        }
        try {
            result = manager.getElement(id).getString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtil.error(TAG, "getString -> IOException");
        } catch (NotExistException e) {
            LogUtil.error(TAG, "getString -> NotExistException");
        } catch (WrongTypeException e) {
            LogUtil.error(TAG, "getString -> WrongTypeException");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and Usage would be,

```java
String appName = getString(context, ResourceTable.String_appname);
```